# How to organize a Apache Spark Project

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I would like to understand how to best setup a project. I will use maven for building including tests.

I wrote my first Spark application but to launch it during developent, I had to run in in local mode:

```
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                                  .appName("RDDTest")
                                  .master("local")
                                  .getOrCreate();
```

However, if I want to submit it to a cluster, it would run still in local mode which I do not want.

So I would have to change the code before deployment, build the jar and submit it to the cluster. Obviously this is not the best approach.

I was wondering what is the best practice? Do you externalize the master URL somehow?

Comment: When you submit to a cluster, it also runs in client mode.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you only want to run spark in local mode from test cases. So your main job shouldn't have ant local mode associated.

Also, all the parameters which spark accepts should come from command line. for example the App Name, master etc should be taken from command line only instead hard coding.

Try to keep the dataframe manipulations in small functions so they could be tested independently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `spark-submit` script. 
You can find further documentation here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

I would have all methods to take a SparkContext as parameter (maybe even implicit parameters). Next, I would either use Maven profiles to define parameters for the SparkContext (test/prod) or alternatively program arguments.

An easy alternative would just be to programmtically  define one SparkContext for your (prod) main method (cluster-mode), and a separate one for your tests (local-mode)